# How can I insert an image sequence into Blender's Video Sequence Editor?

Tags: video, images, blender, composite-video

I just started to play with Blender's Video Sequence Editor.

I see I can add Image(static) and Movie.
Can I add an Image Sequence ? If so how ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Old thread I know.  Basically, you just select add an image and then select multiple images in the file selection dialog. Just right mouse click on the first file and drag over all the images you want to select.  Usually its best to put all the image files in a separate directory first and just press 'a' to select them all.  You can also specify a wildcard to select them in the field below the one that shows the directory.  You can put something like 0*.jpg in there and press enter and it will select all the ones that match.

Once you press the select image button, it will give you a sequence to drag into place in the sequence editor.  You can move around just like any other sequence.

This is how I typically animate. I render a bunch of stills and then animate the frames.

Comment: Is there a way to treat a sequence of frames like this so that the first can be held for x frames then the second one for y frames, etc.? (Or something like that.) I'm trying to place a sequence of subtitle images that I generated with a GIMP script and would like to be able to cue them and have them fade in and out.

Comment: If you just add one image at a time you can stretch them out individually. In fact, by default they are added to the sequence editor as an image that lasts for 40 frames.

Comment: right, but I was trying to avoid needing to do all of that work manually (I have more than 100 subtitles/captions to sequence and have already set up all the cue points in a file). If I had done them all manually then if I wanted to change them later, say to use a different font, then I'd end up going back and changing each one. This seems like it would be a good use case for a script that interacted with Blender, but as I've not written one of those before I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: from https://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-161848.html Hotkey: -> Y 
Menu: Strip -> Separate Images to Strips